# Angular 2/4 components communication thru a service

Tags: angular

I have 2 components and 1 service that is shared:

Parent components display all companies, and the child has removeCompany method.

Problem is that when the I call the removeCompany method, the getCompanies() from parent is not updated(removeCompany() works if i call it in the parent);

What am I missing?

```
export class CompanyService {

  // Placeholder for last id so we can simulate automatic incrementing of id's
  private lastId = 0;
  // variable for holding companies
  private companies: Company[] =  [];

  // URL mockup web API
  private backendData = 'api/companies';

  constructor ( private http: Http ) {
    // Populate the companies variable on instantiation
    this.http.get(this.backendData)
      .map( (response: Response) => response.json().data )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        data.forEach(company => {
          this.companies.push(company);
          if (company.id > this.lastId) { this.lastId = company.id; }
        });
      });
  }

  // Simulate GET /companies
  getAllcompanies(): Company[] {
    return this.companies;
  }
  // Simulate DELETE /companies/:id
  deleteCompanyById(id: number): CompanyService {
    this.companies = this.companies
      .filter(company => company.id !== id);
    return this;
  }
```

Components:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {}

  get companies() {
    return this.companyService.getAllcompanies();
  }
}

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()company: Company;

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {}

  removeCompany(company: Company): CompanyService {
    console.log(company);
    return this.companyService.deleteCompanyById(company.id);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<parent *ngFor="company of companies">
  <child id="child" [company]="company">
    ...button (click)="removeCompany(company)"....
  </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Why are you return the Service when deleting the company?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is , `ParentComponent` is not aware that `ChildCompany` deleted a company. To fix that , use `BehaviorSubject` in the service:

---

Instead of

```
private companies: Company[] =  [];
```

Use

```
private companies = new BehaviorSubject<Company[]>([]);
```

---

Instead of

```
this.companies.push(company)
```

Use

```
this.companies.next([...this.companies.value, company]);
```

---

Instead of

```
this.companies = this.companies
      .filter(company => company.id !== id);
```

Use

```
this.companies.next(this.companies.value
      .filter(company => company.id !== id));
```

---

Instead of

```
getAllcompanies(): Company[] {
    return this.companies;
}
```

Use

```
getAllcompanies(): Observable<Company[]> {
    return this.companies;
}
```

---

You need to subscribe inside the components.

```
get companies() {
    return this.companyService.getAllcompanies()
               .subscribe(companies => this.companies = companies );
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but it's still not working. I will add a plunkr soon. Learning the new angular feels like climbing a ice wall

Comment: yes it is. too many things to learn even for a small thing . Pass on the plnkr and I will help you